# Rails form_for populates model with Nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, form-for

I am having trouble populating my model with my parameter passed from form_for as it assigns Nil to the id, my column (decrypted), and created/updated at fields.

Below is my view (new.html.erb):

```
  <%= form_for @decrypt_text, url: { action: "create" }  do |f| %>  
  <div class="field"> 
    <%= f.label :decrypt_text %><br> 
    <%= f.text_area :decrypted %><br> 
  </div> 
  <div class="actions"> 
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %> 
  </div> 
 <% end %>
```

and my controller:

```
class DecryptController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @decrypt_text = Dmessage.new
  end

  def create
      @decrypt_text = Dmessage.new(params[:decrypted]) 
      p @decrypt_text

      if @decrypt_text.save 
        redirect_to '/decrypt/display' 
      else 
        redirect_to '/' 
      end     
  end

  def display
    @displayme = Dmessage.order("created_at").last
  end

end
```

and just in case, my model:

```
class CreateDmessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :dmessages do |t|
      t.text :decrypted
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

I know it's assigning nil values because this:

```
 p @decrypt_text
```

prints out:

```
#<Dmessage id: nil, decrypted: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I really am not sure what I am missing but I am fairly new to Rails. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the params log genearted while submitting the form?

Comment: Are you using Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, remove `url: { action: "create" }` from your form. It is unnecessary for the reason that Rails is smart enough to understand that if `@decrypt_text` doesn't exist, it will trigger the necessary `create` action.

However, what I really think is causing you trouble is that you are not making use of **strong parameters** in your application (`@decrypt_text = Dmessage.new(params[:decrypted])`). You are trying to initialize a params hash directly, which is really dangerous. As of Rails version 4.x it is not allowed to initialize params hashes directly in this way, you must use strong params, to prevent mass assignment.

These would be the changes that I would personally make in your controller file...

```
class DecryptController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @decrypt_text = Dmessage.new
  end

  def create
    @decrypt_text = Dmessage.new(decrypt_params) 

    if @decrypt_text.save 
      redirect_to '/decrypt/display' 
    else 
      redirect_to '/' 
    end     
  end

  def display
    @displayme = Dmessage.order("created_at").last
  end

  private

    def decrypt_params
      params.require(:dmessage).permit(:decrypted)
    end
end
```

Comment: Tim, thanks for the tip on strong params, worked like a charm. However, when I remove url: { action: "create" } , I get the following error: `undefined method `dmessages_path' ` , which is why I included it in the first place. Can you give me any further insight on this?

Comment: Hmm this could actually be happening for various reasons. One thing that I suspect is that you might be missing `resources :dmessages` in your **routes.rb** file. Could you please check that for me please? If you don't have it, please make sure to include it. Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 1):

if u are using rails 4.x then your have to make use of strong parameters as of Rails version 4.x it is not allowed to initialize params hashes directly.

Add following private method to your controller,
  def decrypt_params
      params.require(:dmessage).permit(:decrypted)
    end

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ***Rails 3***, the problem is this line

```
@decrypt_text = Dmessage.new(params[:decrypted])
```

It should be

```
@decrypt_text = Dmessage.new(params[:dmessage])
```